# Selecting An Item From A Drop Down List

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I am trying to select an item from a drop down list. I have put the code in the section below. My research has not been conclusive though:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278281/how-to-select-an-option-from-drop-down-using-selenium-webdriver-c
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471515/select-a-value-from-drop-down-using-selenium-webdriver-c-sharp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535069/select-each-option-in-a-drop-down-using-selenium-webdriver-c-sharp

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CV_Lib_Do_Not_Use
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiate Firefox Driver
            //Go to CV Library Website
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.cv-library.co.uk/");

            //Wait for web element to become visible
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);


            //Click on Search Jobs tab
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("header-link-searchjobs")).Click();

            //Use the 'Keywords / Job Title / Job Ref' search field to search for a Test Analyst position 
            var position = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='searchjobs_form']/div[1]/div[1]/input"));

            //Type Test Analyst in the search box
            position.SendKeys("Test Analyst");

            //Use the 'Keywords / Job Title / Job Ref' search field to search for a Test Analyst position 
            var location = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='location']"));

            //Type Manchester in the search box
            location.SendKeys("Manchester");


            //Identify xpath for distance from desired location 
            var distance = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='distance_adv']"));


            //Click on 10 miles from the drop-down
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='distance_adv']/option[6]")).Click();



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can/should utilize the [`SelectElement` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296364/771848) which conveniently abstracts away the "select-option" HTML blocks:

```
var distance = driver.FindElement(By.Id("distance_adv"));
var selectDistance = new SelectElement(distance);

selectDistance.SelectByText("10 miles");
```